# does calling a shell command from within a scripting language slow down performance?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, shell

When writing python, perl, ruby, or php 
I'll often use ...

```
PERL:
`[SHELL COMMAND HERE]`
system("[SHELL]", "[COMMAND]", "[HERE]")

Python
import os
os.system("[SHELL COMMAND HERE]")
from subprocess import call
call("[SHELL]", "[COMMAND]", "[HERE]")

ruby 
`[SHELL COMMAND HERE]`
system("[SHELL COMMAND HERE]")

PHP
shell_exec ( "SHELL COMMAND HERE" )
```

How much does spawning a subprocess in the shell slow down the performance of a program?
For example, I was just writing a script with perl and libcurl, and it was difficult, with all of libcurl's parameters, to get it to work. I stopped using libcurl and just started using `curl` and the performance seemed to IMPROVE, scripting became much easier, and furthermore, I could run my script on systems that only had basic perl (no cpan modules) and the basic shell utilities installed.

Why is spawning this subshell considered bad programming practice? Should it be, always in theory, much slower than using a specific binding/equivalent library within the language?

Comment: Its usually considered bad for security not necessarily perfromance (at least in php). In fact the shell utility sometimes faster to execute that doing something with the available API in the language.

Comment: security I can certainly understand...why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: it also depends if you call something a lot in a loop or so I would say... this would be bad practice to use shell-calls there I would say. But if you just call it once, or once in a while... who cares (for performance)?

Comment: As I used to be more of a "sysadmin" I always tended to use shell-commands in perl as well because I knew exactly what they did and I had my job done quickly. Now as I am more into Perl programming only (not caring for sysadmin at all) I never use shell-commands to ensure that the code is independent from the system... so I do think what your target and motivation is, is the main thing to decide if you should or not. It kind of depends it you need code like a "hammer" to do it quick and dirty or like a "pencil" to do art. :-)

Comment: You say "I stopped using libcurl and just started using curl and the performance seemed to IMPROVE."  The first rule of optimization is that you must measure.  You can't go off of "seemed to".  Measure yourself to be sure.

Comment: You can always benchmark and see...in gneral they all take a small speed hit to spawn a separate new process...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first reason why executing shell commands is bad is maintainability. Context switching between tasks is bad enough without language switching. Security is also a consideration but coding practice will make it less significant (avoid injections, ...)

There are several factors that impact performance:

1. Forking a process: This takes a while but in case the code being executed performs well, this becomes less significant.
2. Optimization becomes impossible: When the control is handed over to another process, the interpreter or compiler cannot perform any optimizations. Also, you cannot perform any optimizations.
3. Blocking: Shell commands are blocking operations. They will not be scheduled like a native part of the code would.
4. Parsing: If there is a need to do something about the output, it needs to be parsed. In native code, the data would already be in a relevant data structure. Parsing is also prone to errors.
5. Command line generation: Generating a command line for an executable may require iterating. Sometimes that takes more cycles than performing the same natively.

Most of these problems arise when the external command is executed in a loop. It may be easy to find examples where none of these become a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Who says spawning a shell process is bad practice?  Beware the dogmatists.  There is no hard and fast rule that will define when to do it or not to do it.  In your example, when you started shelling out to curl, you finished your project faster and you got better performance.
The proof is *always in the pudding*.

As far as performance goes, forking (and exec'ing) a new process induces a hit so you should avoid it for operations that are short.  But if the sub-process runs for a few seconds, you won't notice the 25ms (just a place holder #) it takes to spin it up.  But if there's a transient function that runs very quick, that you call often, calling it via sub-shell will induce a significant performance hit.

One thing about subprocesses is that they are independently testable from the command line.  So they are really stand alone tools, and this can be highly useful for some problems.

One last thing to consider.  If you believe in the "right tool for the job", and the right tool happens to already to be on the box, and you can solve the task at hand by shelling out to it, then why not?  I've seen so much code in my life that was ultimately irrelevant as the problem was already solved by some freely available (and already installed) tool.  It just happened to not fit into the monolithic (read single-tool) implementation environment chosen by the programmers.

The corollary being "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail".  Don't be afraid to reach for the screwdriver, and beware the "one hammer to rule them all" cultists.

Answer (score 4):

Ferrix stated several of the performance-related issues quite nicely.

Regarding security and maintainability, I would submit the following:

1. Portability/isolation from external dependencies

   - Sure, you can shell out to call `wget`--if you're on Linux.  On Windows or Mac, it'll die horribly, and you'll either have to explain to your boss why you have to re-write it to use the built-in methods, or support the users/co-workers who need to use your tool (neither of which will be very fun).
   - Someday you'll spend hours trying to figure out why your script no longer works, only to find that the upgraded version of your external program needs different command-line parameters and no longer works the way your code expects.
2. Escape characters in one language (Perl/Python/PHP) don't necessarily map to escape characters in the shell language (ex: an SQL-injection attack is arguably the result of non-escaped characters in one language (HTML) being mixed with a different language (SQL)).
3. Debugging is hard enough in one language--trying to debug a command that generates a command for another language is even harder (especially when escaping quotation-marks, it's easy to end up with strings like `\\\\\"some value\\\\\"`...)